# `this` variable is not accessible outside js methods or packages in angular2 typescript

Tags: javascript, angular

`this` variable is not accessible outside js methods or packages in angular2 typescript.

```js
public mousekeyAction() {
            var mc=0,kc=0;           
        gkm.events.on('key.pressed', function (data) {
          this.keyscount= kc++;
          console.log(this.keyscount);
        });
        // Listen to all mouse events (click, pressed, released, moved, dragged)
        gkm.events.on('mouse.*', function (data) {
            this.mousecount=mc++;
           console.log(this.mousecount);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Assign `this` to another variable outside `callbacks`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use `fat arrow` as function/callback instead of simple function. this will maintain the scope of this even outside the function too.

Use your function like this :-

```
public mousekeyAction() {
        var mc=0,kc=0;           
        gkm.events.on('key.pressed', (data) => {
            this.keyscount= kc++;
            console.log(this.keyscount);
        });
        // Listen to all mouse events (click, pressed, released, moved, dragged)
        gkm.events.on('mouse.*', (data) => {
            this.mousecount=mc++;
            console.log(this.mousecount);
        });
    }
```

for more info refer here

- https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/arrow-functions.html

Comment: The scope of *this* is always the current execution context. For arrow functions, *this* is lexical and adopted from the *this* of the execution context in which they are defined.

Answer (score 0):

Assign `this` to another variable as below

```
public mousekeyAction() {
  var mc = 0,
    kc = 0,
    self = this;
  gkm.events.on('key.pressed', function(data) {
    self.keyscount = kc++;
    console.log(self.keyscount);
  });
  // Listen to all mouse events (click, pressed, released, moved, dragged)
  gkm.events.on('mouse.*', function(data) {
    self.mousecount = mc++;
    console.log(self.mousecount);
  });
}
```

Since `callback` context is different from context of expected `this`.

Comment: @PardeepJain Y so?

Comment: this will refer to the  `gkm.events.on` function instance thats y this will not work according to me

Comment: can i  use self.keyscount anywhere as global?

Comment: @praveenkumars not anywhere only inside the method it is defined.

Comment: @jyithi I found a complete solution using arrow function allows to use this inside jsfunction

Comment: @praveenkumars Yes, It'll work but it's an es6 standard.